Why does the NoSuchMethodException problem occur when activemq-all is introduced?
When I introduced activemq-all in jetty and deployed the application, a NoSuchMethodException error occurred. However, when I introduced the activemq-client dependency, the error disappeared.
The following is an error.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17cf8886.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:912)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.access$000(Enhancer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:502)


As the name suggests, the activemq-all dependency contains all the dependencies for the ActiveMQ Classic broker and client including its own Spring dependencies. You definitely should not be including it in your Spring application as it is likely to cause conflicts. That is, in fact, why you're seeing the NoSuchMethodException.
You should only need to depend on activemq-client if you're integrating via JMS.
